# imagemagick command-line -shadow like photoshop inner-shadow problems

Tags: css, imagemagick

I'm trying to create a Photoshop inner-shadow effect, same as css3 box-shadow inset effect.

Step 1 (i'm generating button - rounded rectangle):

```
convert -size 220x50 xc:none -fill '#bdbdbd' -draw 'roundrectangle 0,0 219,49 25,25' /var/www/test.local/public/images/button.png
```

I got an image - it's ok:

[image: step 1]
<sub>(source: [artshevtsov.ru](http://artshevtsov.ru/button.png))</sub>

Step 2 (now i'd like to get a result you can see on image below, i've made it with Photoshop):

[step 2 http://wellkin.info/re/rounded.jpg](http://wellkin.info/re/rounded.jpg)

How to apply this effect to my rounded rectangle, using imagemagick -shadow and maybe some options like repage or compose?

P.S.: i can't find any example here http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#shadow that works for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discussion moved to imagemagick board, my question solved here: 
http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=23417&p=98450#p98514